# Efficient way to create and fill an array with consecutive numbers in range

Tags: javascript, arrays, numbers

for the moment i use this JavaScript
to create an array with n numbers from 0 to n

```
// javascript populate array 
var n=1000;
var arr=[n];
for (i=n;i>=0;i--) {
arr[i]=i;
console.log(arr[i]);
}
```

is it the fast/right way to do the task?

Comment: for n=100000; got 15ms.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do declarative approach while using `Array.from` like this:

```js
arr = Array.from({length: 20}, (e, i)=> i)
console.log(arr)
```

Comment: merely as fast as cycle iteration method 25 vs 15. ms with n=100000

Comment: Can you expand on how this works? I've read the MDN documentation but need an ELI5. How does {length: 20} work and how do I look this up?

Comment: @pmath325 Under Description on MDN: `array-like objects (objects with a length property and indexed elements).` You create a new Object with a length property as required (i.e.-20): `Array.from` looks at that length property and tries to index the Object for each index in length (0...19). It gets Undefined as the value at each index, and passes (Value,Index) to the arrow function. The arrow function then returns the Index, which is collected by `Array.from`.

Answer (score 8):

An ES6 way of doing it using [`Array.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/keys):

```js
let n = 10;
let arr = Array.from(Array(n).keys());

console.log(arr);
```

---

Made a quick JSPerf with answer so far:

https://jsperf.com/array-filling-so/

Comment: there is big dispersion of duration time value from 19ms to 50ms. but that is merely fast method. (n=1000000);

Answer (score 5):

If by efficient you mean ‘least number of characters’, I think this is shorter than any of the answers posted:

```
[...Array(10).keys()]
```

Things like this come in handy when testing stuff using the browser console. Be warned though that it's more than twice as slow as the currently accepted answer of:

```
Array.from({length:10},(e,i)=>i)
```

Although I haven't professionally tested the performance, I tried creating an array with 1e8 elements using both methods and it took about five seconds using the first method and just two using the second method (with considerable variability for both methods) on my little laptop whereas an array with 1e9 elements caused it to run out of memory.

But for people who need to enter stuff like this into the browser console regularly, that might not matter as much as ease of remembrance and entry. Note however that if you're going to feed the result immediately into a `.map()` the first method is only one character shorter and the performance will be even worse in comparison, particularly because the second method doesn't need a separate `.map()` call. So, only for debugging or trying stuff out, but still useful in my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `map` skipping the first param of the predicate and getting the index `i`.

```js
let arr = Array(10).fill().map((_, i) => i);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: short, but slow.~35ms vs 15ms

Answer (score 1):

The shortest way (I think) `[...Array(10)].map((a,b)=>b)`

```js
console.log(
  [...Array(10)].map((a,b)=>b)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Array.from(Array(1000).keys());`
Is the fasted so far in v8 engine.
Dont listent other.
https://jsbench.me/jdjxrdszul/2

Answer (score 0):

Slightly optimized by using a while loop:

```
let i = 1000;
const arr = [0];
while (i) {
  arr[i] = i;
  i--;
}
```

[image]