# How to use Array.fill to create 0...499 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I want to use `Array.fill` method to create a sequence from 0...499 like

```
const arr = []
for(let i = 0; i < 500; i++)
   arr.push(i);
```

Currently, I am using `Array.from` like:

```
const arr = Array.from(Array(500).keys())
```

But how can I use just `Array.fill` to create the sequence? Is it even possible?

Comment: I don't think you can. `Array.fill` fills the array with the same values, not different values.

Comment: My counter question would be "why?"

Comment: You can't DOC says _"The fill() method fills (modifies) all the elements of an array from a start index (default zero) to an end index (default array length) with a **static value**. It returns the modified array"._

Comment: Just use `Array.from`, i.e. `Array.from({ length: N }, (v, i) => i)`

Comment: @Terry He knows the other methods. That's why I didn't close this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579499/efficient-way-to-create-and-fill-an-array-with-consecutive-numbers-in-range

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No you can't do it with fill alone as fill method adds a static value

> The fill() method fills (modifies) all the elements of an array from a
>   start index (default zero) to an end index (default array length) with
>   a static value. It returns the modified array.

```js
console.log(new Array(500).fill(0).map((_,i) => i ))
console.log(Array.from(Array(500).keys()))
```

Comment: I didn't downvote. But I'd use `forEach()` to modify the array that was created with `fill`, rather than creating a new array with `map()`

Comment: @Barmar i have added that just as an example to demonstrate

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use `fill` alone to do what you ask. You'll have to combine it with one or more other methods.

I can't say I *recommend* this approach, because it really doesn't feel like idiomatic JavaScript, but just for demonstration purposes, here's a solution that uses `fill` to populate the resulting array (instead of just using it to get around the awkwardness of the Array constructor). It's also more verbose and probably less performant than the alternatives.

```js
console.log(Array.from({ length: 500 }).reduce((x, y, i, a) => (a.fill(i, i, i + 1), a), []))
```

For what it's worth, I find `Array.from({ length: 500 }, (_, i) => i)` as [@Terry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56906727/how-to-use-array-fill-to-create-0-499-in-javascript#comment100358261_56906727) suggested to be a much more elegant.

Comment: I prefer `Array.from(Array(N),(_,i)=>i)` or `[...Array(N)].map((_,i)=>i)`.. although if it were possible, give me `Array(N).map(i)` any day. No one really uses `_` anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a one-line helper like this:

```js
function createArrayWithNumbersFromRange(start: number, end: number): number[] {
  return [...Array(end - start + 1)].map((_, index) => start + index);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could generate an Iterator and push it to a new array.

```js
[...Array(5).keys()];
 => [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: the question is different