# how to create array from 17 to 120

Tags: javascript, arrays

what is the fastest way to create array from number 17 to number 120?

```
[17,18,20,...,118,119,120]
```

I tried to use Array method but its start with 0 and slice from some resson cut the last numbers and not the firsts numbers.

```
export const ARR_OF_AGES = Array(121).fill().slice(16).map((x, i) => {
  return { value: i, label: i }
})
```

Comment: A simple for loop would suffice

Comment: do you have some example?

Comment: of a `for` loop?

Comment: `Array(121-17).fill().map((x, i) => {  return { value: i+17, label: i+17 }})`

Comment: Dupe of: [Create array of all integers between two numbers, inclusive, in Javascript/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069315/create-array-of-all-integers-between-two-numbers-inclusive-in-javascript-jquer) or [Efficient way to create and fill an array with consecutive numbers in range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579499/efficient-way-to-create-and-fill-an-array-with-consecutive-numbers-in-range), ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following should work.

```
Array.from({length: 120 - 17 + 1}, (_, i) => i + 17)
```

See working example below:

```js
const result = Array.from({length: 104}, (_, i) => i + 17)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: might as well show the math for clarity `Array.from({length: 120-17+1}, (_, i) => i + 17)` (and avoid the error you just fixed :))

Answer (score 0):

If your array starts with 17 and ends with 120 it means it has 104 elements. So change 121 to 104 in your code, and instead of giving value "i" to your elements, give them value "i+17". That way your i-th element will have value i+17 meaning your array will start from 17

Comment: Don't forget to remove the `.slice(16)` then.

Comment: It would be nice if some code would follow the explanation :)

Comment: oh, yeah, i didn't see the slice. Tnx!

Comment: `Array((120-17+1)/*104*/).fill().map((x, i) => { return { value: i + 17, label: i + 17 } })`

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for "fastest", and I suggested using a [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop in the comments above, I thought that'd I'd at least give you a simple example:

```
let ary = [];
for (let i = 17; i <= 120; i++) {
  ary.push(i);
}
```

Running some [simple performance tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111368/how-do-you-performance-test-javascript-code) shows that this method is over an order of magnitude faster then the result you accepted. So yeah, fast. And easy to understand.