# Creating an array from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm learning Javascript and I'm wondering what the most elegant way to convert this: [1,8]
into this:[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What have you attempted? Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. ([It will involve a loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)).

Comment: That would basically be a "print all nums from x to y" question with an array as output. If you're asking for the most elegant way I'd recommend finding a working way first.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean now that I re-read it.

Comment: @JoelHager I believe it's 'given two bounds, return all integers between (inclusive) those bounds' or something of the sort.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an array containing 1...N](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3746725/how-to-create-an-array-containing-1-n)

Comment: or [how to create array from 17 to 120](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70067717/how-to-create-array-from-17-to-120) which has links to multiple relevant duplicates

Answer (score 1):

```js
const argarray = [1, 8]

const countToN = (array) => {
  // init results array
  let res = []
  // start at the first value array[0] go *up to* the second array[1]
  for (let i = array[0]; i <= array[1]; i++) {
    res.push(i)
  }
  // return the result
  return res
}

console.log(countToN([1, 10]))
```

This would accommodate what you're trying to do, but it's fairly brittle. You'd have to check that it's an array and that it has only 2 values. If you had other requirements, I could amend this to account for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without loops. Note that this **only** works with positive numbers. It supports arrays of any length, but will always base the result off of the first and last values.

```js
const case1 = [1, 8];
const case2 = [5, 20];

const startToEnd = (array) => {
    const last = array[array.length - 1];
    const newArray = [...Array(last + 1).keys()];

    return newArray.slice(array[0], last + 1);
};

console.log(startToEnd(case1));
console.log(startToEnd(case2));
```

Here's a solution that works for negative values as well:

```js
const case1 = [-5, 30];
const case2 = [-20, -10];
const case3 = [9, 14];

const startToEndSolid = (array) => {
    const length = array[array.length - 1] - array[0] + 1;

    if (length < 0) throw new Error('Last value must be greater than the first value.');

    return Array.from(Array(length)).map((_, i) => array[0] + i);
};

console.log(startToEndSolid(case1));
console.log(startToEndSolid(case2));
console.log(startToEndSolid(case3));
```

Answer (score 0):

[A simple `for` loop will do it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement). Here's an example that has error checking and allows you to range both backwards and forwards (ie `[1, 8]`, and also `[1, -8]`).

```js
function range(arr) {

  // Check if the argument (if there is one) is
  // an array, and if it's an array it has a length of
  // of two. If not return an error message.
  if (!Array.isArray(arr) || arr.length !== 2) {
    return 'Not possible';
  }

  // Deconstruct the first and last elements
  // from the array
  const [ first, last ] = arr;

  // Create a new array to capture the range
  const out = [];

  // If the last integer is greater than the first
  // integer walk the loop forwards
  if (last > first) {
    for (let i = first; i <= last; i++) {
      out.push(i);
    }

  // Otherwise walk the loop backwards
  } else {
    for (let i = first; i >= last; i--) {
      out.push(i);
    }
  }

  // Finally return the array
  return out;

}

console.log(range([1, 8]));
console.log(range('18'));
console.log(range());
console.log(range([1]));
console.log(range([-3, 6]));
console.log(range([9, 16, 23]));
console.log(range([4, -4]));
console.log(range([1, -8, 12]));
console.log(range(null));
console.log(range(undefined));
console.log(range([4, 4]));
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array#map` as follows:

```js
const input = [1,8],

      output = [...Array(input[1] - input[0] + 1)]
      .map((_,i) => input[0] + i);
      
      
console.log( output );
```